# How does implicit type constructor differs from explicit type constructor?

Tags: c#, oop, clr

```
public class ImplicitTypeConstructor
{
    public static int implicitInt = 10;
}

public class ExplicitTypeConstructor
{
    public static int explicitInt;
    static ExplicitTypeConstructor()
    {
        explicitInt = 10;
    }
}
```

How do these implementations differs from each other?

Comment: Well the second code wouldn't even compile, to start with... What sort of implementation difference are you interested in?

Comment: Sorry for the access modifier.

Comment: Either of them will set field with specified value. Value set in constructor is equal to field initializer, `explicitInt` field initializer occurs before constructor, so it will always be `999` (see example of [static field initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx), which can cause problem but is not related to constructor). You'd rather leave field uninitialized then.

Comment: The CLR does not support initializers for static fields.  The C# compiler solves this by rewriting your code from the 1st to the 2nd syntax.  There *is* a difference, the 1st syntax turns on the *beforefieldinit* attribute on the class.  Which relaxes the rules the CLR needs to observe when deciding to call the type initializer.  An optimization that matters when the class is used in a lot of appdomains.  That can byte in special cases.